# on hover border gradient fills background

Tags: html, css, css-animations, font-awesome

I'm have a fa icon with a rounded border with a gradient, when i put a hover effect to rotate the icon, the background fills with the border gradient. I want to leave the background transparent while the icon rotates.

Here is the **[codepen](https://codepen.io/fernandob/pen/dWeYKG?editors=1100)** .. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.circle-icon {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}
.circle-icon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #3BB44A 0%, #4DA5EC 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.fa {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: .5em;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #4DA5EC;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.fa:hover {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Is the goal to rotate the gradient border and the arrow (as it does now, minus the fill) or just the arrow in the middle?

Comment: @wpalmes just the arrow. when i hover over the element, border and icon, the arrow should just rotate.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by using a pseudo-selector on the fa-chevron-down class.

```
.fa-chevron-down:before{
  background:white;
   border-radius:50%;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Does the trick, but the gradient still rotates. Close enough?

Comment: This is true.  Looks cool to me, but I'll leave that up to the OP.

Comment: thanks folks, i also managed to find a way to keep the circle fixed while only the icon rotates by putting the icon with in a div with the border css. you can check it out here https://codepen.io/fernandob/pen/BRxzJZ?editors=1100